# How to select element outside DOM without event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I need to execute:

```
$('.btn-toolbar').toolbar({
    content: '#toolbar-options'
});
```

Elements with `.btn-toolbar` class are not in *DOM* because are added after and ajax request. **How can I select elements outside DOM?**.

In other similar question it's solved with Delegate Event, but I don´t have any event for managing it, I don´t need enable click on it, hover or any other event. I just want to execute toolbar function for all elements with `btn-toolbar`, but `$('.btn-toolbar')` is empty at this time.

Comment: Where is the element if not in the DOM? Will it be added later to the DOM?

Comment: If it's not in DOM... You can't select it. If it's not *yet* in DOM, you need event delegation. There is nothing else possible from what I know.

Comment: Use the variable which has the stored off-DOM element instead of `$('.btn-toolbar')`. The element has to exist somewhere if you want to access it.

Comment: *« I don´t have any event for manage.»* -- Post more code.... And we'll find you one ;)

Comment: @marekful Yes, it will be added after an ajax request.

Comment: In that case you have to execute your sample code in the callback of that ajax to initialise the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the code on the ajax call success/complete after it places the elements of class .btn-toolbar in the DOM.

```
$.ajax({
....
}).done(function() {
  // Places/Inserts the .btn-toolbar elements in the page.
  $('.btn-toolbar').toolbar({
    content: '#toolbar-options'
  });
});
```

If the ajax call is made by some other script where you cannot(for example - by some other plugin's minified script, or that script is from other site) inject your code, still you can interfere on the ajax call and attach your code to be run after.
You can use [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) to customize the ajax calls made in your site.

For example you can run your code whenever an ajax call completes successfully by:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('.btn-toolbar').toolbar({
    content: '#toolbar-options'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element is not in any element subtree (i.e. not a child of any other element), and you aren't holding a reference to it (nor is any other object referencing it), it's effectively gone, and subject to garbage collection.

If you *are* holding a reference to it, you will need to use that reference. If it's a child of some other element (whether or not *that* element is in the DOM tree), you'll need to include that parent element in your selection, which means you will need at least a reference to that parent element. Otherwise you don't really have any other way of reaching it.

If the element doesn't actually exist yet, and you're just saying "invoke this command on any `.btn-toolbar` as it gets loaded into the page", then you need a mutation observer.